# Expose azure app configuration as env var or config map in AKS service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, configmap, azure-app-configuration

My requirement is to use azure app configuration in my spring boot microservice (deployed on AKS) as environment variable or config map, since I cannot update the service to use the starter package as mentioned in MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-java-spring-app?tabs=spring-boot-3).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What is the best approach to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Azure App Configuration in Kubernetes but without changing app code, you can use **Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider**. More information can be found in the document below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-kubernetes-service

Comment: I am evaluating this feature but since its currently in a preview state, so Microsoft does not recommend its usage in production environment. Furthermore, Microsoft does not provide support for features that are still in the preview stage. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Here is an alternative solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/integrate-kubernetes-deployment-helm

Comment: So with this approach, as per my understanding, if there is any change in app configuration value, export of config values along with helm upgrade needs to be done for reflecting the values in kubernetes. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: For Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider, is Config map updated if there is any change in app configuration key/value? Also can I mount the the config map created by provider in a volume so that app pod get the updated key/value on periodic sync?

Comment: Looks like these are the same questions as the GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/781. We can follow up from there.